# How to concatenate a columns in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Considering this **customer** table with the following columns:

- first_name
- middle_name
- sur_name
- extension

thus:

```
id       first_name      middle_name     sur_name      extension
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        John            null            Doe            null
2        Harry           Noah            Potter         null
3        Sam             Smith           Doe            III
4        Hero            null            Finch          null
```

and i made this raw query:

```
$customer = DB::select("select c.* from customers c where concat_ws(', ' ,c.sur_name,concat_ws(' ',concat_ws(' ',c.first_name,c.middle_name),c.extension)) like ?", [$item]);
```

How can i convert it into Model base like `Customer::where()->first()` with a handling of null values (concat_ws, in the case of mysql)?

Comment: I think its not handling the null value from my database.

Comment: If you use the attribute getter as suggested in that link, you pull all the data (null or not) and then use a model attribute to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code.

```
 $costomers = Customer::select(DB::raw("CONCAT('first_name','last_name') AS Name"))->get();
```

Hope You Help!!